# UTC/GMT: Getting the Offset

Tags: linux, windows, cmd

I'm currently in EST.  On my Windows machine, running this command

```
systeminfo | find "Time Zone"
```

yields "Time Zone:                 (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"

So it would seem as if we are 5 hours behind UTC/GMT.

But in Linux I run:

```
date +%z
```

and I get: "-0400"

In Linux when I run the date command I get: "Fri Sep 21 15:00:45 EDT 2012"

So I'm not sure whether we are 4 or 5 hours behind UTC/GMT.  I found this issue because I opened an Atom feed using Firefox and IE.

The "updated" date on the feed is "2011-11-09T15:28:23Z", which is the time in UTC.

IE displays the local time in the browser as: "11:28:23 AM" while Firefox displays "10:28 AM".  Can anyone explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Do both Windows and Linux agree on the time?  If not, which one agrees with your (non-computer) clock?

Your link says that you live in New York City, which is GMT -5 (the time in Greenwich - 5 hours), and your zone uses Daylight Savings Time (DST) (+1 hour). This put's you in EDT, or Eastern Daylight Time.

You can set that in Windows 7:

**Left-click** on the clock in the bottom-right corner of the screen
Click ==> "**Change Date and Time Settings...**"
[image: Calendar:]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/c3bd60bd1d38365337467f4acd8910503a47cd7accde79665d24bce65c7e037f6g.jpg))</sub>

Click ==> "**Change Time Zone...**"
[image: TimeandDate]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/5f51d709fff7b1bbc503482653aef56f89e29dff6523c837cfbf77f732b419016g.jpg))</sub>

==> select "**(UTC -5:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)**"
==> Checkmark "**Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Savings Time**"
[image: Time Zone]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/conv/8c90c2525dfe390f788c9f7fc21f2be99e5d4859c6121e422a8a1cc8e2697d0f6g.jpg))</sub>

Click ==> **OK** ==> **OK**

Keep in mind that `systeminfo` will **NOT** show your DST setting. I know no method of checking or setting that from the command prompt.

I do not know why Firefox and IE would show different times.

Comment: Both Windows and Linux agree on time and time zone. The Eastern Standard Time and automatically adjust for Daylight Savings Time were already selected.  I'm guessing that Firefox must be assuming that the time zone offset includes the DST as it appears to do so in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the fact that Linux date command will include the daylight saving time depending on the time of the year you run the command on, while on Windows it prints the offset without the DST.